# How to find the first term of the expansion of the function 1/(ln(tgx)) as x goes to pi/4

Tags: real-analysis

[image]How to find expansion of $$\frac{1}{ln(tgx))}$$ as x goes to $$\frac{\pi}{4}$$ If I use expansion of elementary functions I get $$\frac{1}{x-1+o(x))}$$ as it's obviously wrong. Thank you!

Comment: You should do the expansion on $g(x) = \frac{1}{\ln(\tan(x))}$.